# Save & Done Button

Tags: civievent, ui

I use CiviCRM on a few sites, all in Wordpress.

Site A: CivCRM version 5.62.0, the Save & Done button exists in CiviEvent.

Site B: CivCRM version 5.69.2, there are only Save and Cancel buttons in CiviEvent. Additionally, the Manage Events breadcrumb is duplicated. The button is missing on all events, not just recurring.

These site all are current on Wordpress and running on the same server. Changing the theme did not affect the site without the Save & Done button.

I did read through the UI changes that happened in the last year and did not see mention of CiviEvent being among the changes.

Thoughts on how to resolve? Not having Save & Done has been a real PITA on Site B, as I have more events to create on that site.

Comment: Most likely from https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/27029 which was in 5.67

Comment: Maybe, but CiviEvent is not mentioned specifically and it's annoying to Save, then have to 'Cancel' to go back. Doesn't answer the duplicated Manage Events breadcrumbs. I'll leave a comment on the pull and see what feedback I get. Thanks!!

Comment: If you look on the "files" tab it removes a Save and Done button from Manage Events. I don't know about the breadcrumb.

Comment: You can change https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/f0ffff4fe34559958a718deaabd8e4d8c07dc7be/CRM/Event/Form/ManageEvent.php#L184 to read "Manage Event" as a short term fix.

Comment: "it's annoying to Save, then have to 'Cancel' to go back" Agreed, though you could just open the "New Event" screen in a new tab.

Comment: PR for the breadcrumb fix: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29537